# Drone for mavros

Tags: ros, drone, ros-kinetic, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !
So I want to build a small drone(can be tested in lab) and deploy ROS on it. Can anyone help me with what motors and flight controller that I should use to do so ?
I want to use mavros_pkg so want to load Arducopter firmware on the flight controller.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320057/drone-for-mavros/) by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Iv'e been using Navio2 hat for Raspberry Pi3 as FCU in my lab and it has been quite intuitive and easy.
Navio2 software comes pre-installed with ROS and the documentation is great.

As for a drone and motors, just check hobbyking.com and pick something in your budget and preferances.

---

Originally posted by [Benzy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40851/benzy/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0